# Android Can we hide status bar when onAttachedToWindow() is called?

Tags: java, android, status, statusbar

There is a way to hide the status bar or disable it when the onAttachedToWindow is called and window type is keyguard ??
I have tried this on my activity class:

and this is onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock); 
}

public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

and this in my manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen";
```

***but sometimes the status bar disappears, and other times it appears.***

If i try this:

```
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

it gives me the error:

```
12-22 11:03:51.209: E/AndroidRuntime(9088): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

Comment: I would only use the one on the manifest. Also, where are you using it in the manifest?

Comment: I am using in that activity in which i am using onAttachedToWindow. Anyhow as i remember i already tried this, and not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, before you can hide the status bar programmatically you have to request the feature:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

And then to request the fullscreen you can just use:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Here if add requestWindowFeature on activity in onAttachedToWindow() it gives me: 12-22 11:03:51.209: E/AndroidRuntime(9088): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Yeah forgot to add that you need to request it inside `onCreate` and before you call `setContentView`

Comment: I have already implemented in the onCreate and it works properly but when i add onAttachedToWindow, the status appear/disappear randomly. I used onAttachedToWindow because i wanted to disable the home button.

Comment: You can add the flags at `onAttachedToWindow` but what I mean is that you have to request the feature before adding the content view (as the exception says)

Comment: I've added the onCreate method too in this subject.

Comment: Bu, when you add `requestWindowFeature` to the `onCreate` did you remove it from `onAttachedToWindow`?

Comment: Yes, the request was from the beginning in onCreate().

Comment: That's all good; I'm asking if you deleted it from the other place though